# How to do a django select sql or statement?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

I'm not asking on how to do a raw sql. I'm thinking more in terms of the django queryset api.  If I want to execute a sql like

```
select * from table where id="1" or id="2" or id="3";
```

how would I do it using django queryset api?  I know that if you chain filters together you can get AND.  But how would you do OR?

BTW how efficient is the queryset api compared to raw sql, generally the same?

Comment: whoops didn't see the other post there, my bad.  Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Your query is the same as `select * from table where id in ('1', '2', '3');` which using Django queryset will be: `YourModel.objects.filter(id__in=['1', '3', '4'])`.